# Facebook Graph API Explorer not showing Instagram accounts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to connect to Instagram accounts via Facebook following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/) documentation using the Graph API Explorer instead of an app of my own.

However, querying accounts via me/accounts doesn't return any Instagram accounts. I checked all required permissions mentioned in the docs and connected the desired Instagram accounts making sure they are all business accounts.
I also tried to directly access an Instagram account via /{instagram-id}/insights which returned the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (insights) on node type (InstagramUser)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "some id"
  }
}
```

Can you point me into the right direction? As I'm new to the FB API cosomos I might be making some silly mistake.

Comment: _“However, querying accounts via me/accounts doesn't return any Instagram accounts.”_ - doesn't say anywhere that it was supposed to. It lists the pages you have a role on.

Comment: You are right. I was not using the Instagram id, but the connected Facebook page id instead

Answer (score 0):

I found out that uninstalling and installing again the FB app for your Facebook user showed up the missing Instagram Business Accounts